# How can I automate CKAN data exportation to Virtuoso Open Source Edition?

Tags: ckan, virtuoso, openlink-virtuoso

I'm developing an open data portal with Drupal and CKAN. But now client wants to add Virtuoso Open Source service as a SPARQL endpoint and linked data tool.

The system architecture is similar to the [following image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Vyme.png) of [datos.gob.es](https://datos.gob.es) (Spanish government's open data portal).

[image: datos.gob.es system architecture]

I'm having difficulty understanding the data loading dynamics from CKAN to Virtuoso, and official documentation doesn't help at all.

By now I have found next options but do not satisfy my actual problem.

- [Manually Upload `.rdf` files at Quad Store Upload by Conductor Interface](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BcGThrP7m_w) (NOT AUTOMATIC)
- Commercial Version has possibility to connect PostgreSQL CKAN database via ODBC connector. (NOT OPEN SOURCE)
- Use RDF bulk loading process, uploading `.rdf` files to temp directory and launching `ld_dir()` and `rdf_loader_run()` (NOT AUTOMATIC BY DEFAULT)
- [Use Virtuoso Jena Provider](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtJenaProvider) (¿COMPLEX SCENARIO?)

Perfect scenario would be a kind of bypass connection that when you upload new dataset to CKAN automatically upload its rdf file to Virtuoso.

I don't know if i am totally lost with Virtuoso functionality. But is there a way to connect CKAN to Virtuoso so that it gets the `.rdf` or `.ttl` files automatically? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way might be to develop a small cKan extension with a custom plugin that executes when a resource is added, gets the dataset rdf from cKan, and makes and http put request to put the resource in virtuoso.  It looks like virtuoso supports http/put.

http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtRDFInsert#HTTP%20PUT

```
$ curl -T kidehen.n3 http://cname/DAV/home/demo/MyData/ -u demo:demo
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
  <HTML>
    <HEAD>
      <TITLE>201 Created</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
      <H1>Created</H1>Resource /DAV/home/demo/MyData/kidehen.n3 has been created.
    </BODY>
  </HTML>
```

Here's the documentation example on creating a plugin.
https://seanh-ckan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/